# Проверка совпадений с помощью Google Apps Script прямо в Google Forms?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-forms

Собираю через Google Forms ФИО людей и др.данные, и форма записывает их в Google таблицу.

Мне очень нужно теперь, чтобы при заполнении каждого поля форма проверяла нет ли совпадения в Google-таблице. Т.е. этим я проверяю, не отправлял ли этот человек свои данные ранее.

И если во всех трех полях Ф,И,О есть точное совпадение, он выводил на экран сообщение или другой вариант моментального отображения (например поле обводил красным).

Мне кажется с помощью Google Apps Script можно было это сделать, но я в программировании не силен.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не можете этого сделать, т.к. Гугл Формы не имеют API клиентской части.

Comment: А причем здесь API? В Гугл формах есть возможность писать скрипты, разве с помощью них нельзя будет это реализовать?

Comment: Нет "в Формах" писать скрипты нельзя. Почитайте описание метки [tag:google-apps-script] на форуме, специально eё для этого сделал. Вы пишите не "в Формах", а в контейнере, привязанном к Формам.

Comment: SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheetByName(name).getRange("A:A").getValues()      а с помощью этой строки можно что-нибудь похожее сделать?

Comment: Я понимаю ваше ожидание. Вы должны просто принять это как есть - Формы не имеют возможности управления, когда они показываются пользователю. Т.е. в этот момент ничего с ними нельзя сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вы задавали мне вопрос на моем блоге http://disq.us/p/24dufix

Дублирую ответ:
Прямых инструментов нет для реализации такой задачи.

Но есть обходные пути:
1) Вы можете использовать страницы в форме для проверки введенных данных в форму (это крайне неудобно).
2) Вы можете написать веб-апп (веб-страничку) которая будет работать с данными в таблице уже как захотите. Для этого вам понадобятся знания gas html css javascript.

Comment: Я понял вас, спасибо большое!